# time axis settings for histogram in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to understand how the limit of axis works in ggplot histogram. When I tried to set the limit, the histogram shifted.

Below is a script to generate histogram of kWh for each month. On the first graph (p1) I did not set the axis limit. On the second graph (p2) I set the limit, which is the same as the time span of the dataset.

The histograms are attached. On the first histogram, the first bar is correct, for Jan and the value is above 20000.

The problem is: on the second histogram, the first bar is actually for Feb (see the value is below 20000, which is wrong), but the bar in the histogram says Jan.

My question: what causes this time shift? Furthermore, two bars are missing in the second histogram.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
Lines <- "year,month,kWh
2014,1,21535
2014,2,19826
2014,3,20796
2014,4,21249
2014,5,21442
2014,6,22685
2014,7,20569
2014,8,23346
2014,9,23440
2014,10,20148
2014,11,24415
2014,12,21628"
con <- textConnection(Lines)

df = read.csv(con)

df$timestamp = as.POSIXct(paste(df$year,df$month,"01", sep="-"),
                          format="%Y-%m-%d", tz="GMT")

library(ggplot2)

png(filename = "p1.png", width = 800, height = 400, units = "px", pointsize = 24 )

p1 = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = timestamp, kWh)) +
           geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
     scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 month", 
                      date_labels = "%m\n%Y")
p1 

png(filename = "p2.png", width = 800, height = 400, units = "px", pointsize = 24 )

time.start=as.POSIXct("2014-01-01",format="%Y-%m-%d", tz="GMT")
time.end=as.POSIXct("2014-12-01",format="%Y-%m-%d", tz="GMT")

p2 = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = timestamp, kWh)) +
           geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
     scale_x_datetime(limits = c(time.start,time.end),
                      date_breaks = "1 month", 
                      date_labels = "%m\n%Y")
p2
```

[image: The first histogram]

[image: The second histogram]

Comment: not sure but the scale might see the values as ranges of Kwh per month so there is really no value for 01-0214 but there is one going from let's say mid 12-2013 to 01-2014. Try setting: `time.start=as.POSIXct("2013-12-19",format="%Y-%m-%d", tz="GMT")
time.end=as.POSIXct("2014-12-14",format="%Y-%m-%d", tz="GMT")`

Comment: It would seem that `limits = c(time.start-30,time.end+30)` works, with `time.start, time.end` being of class `Date`. Not very satisfactory, though.

Comment: Similarly, `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(time.start, time.end), expand = TRUE)` works as expected.

Comment: Extending the time limit includes the missing bar in the beginning of the data. But that bar is marked as 12-2013, not 01-2014.

Comment: It's truly weird. You might consider asking Hadley / open an issue about this.